# Node.js mysql2 module can't connect

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql2

I'm having a problem connecting to a database through the mysql2 module for Node.js.

Everything worked, before I deleted some file to do with Git.
After reinstalling everything trying to fix it... still doesn't work.

Node outputs:

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:3306
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1300:16)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
at Connection._notifyError

```
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:151:8)
at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:116:3)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21) {
```

errno: -61,
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '::1',
port: 3306,
fatal: true

edit:
In my connection I specify localhost as the host,
and I can connect to the database in the terminal
using the same user as my connection object.

Comment: Maybe the MySQL server on your machine is not running? Or maybe it is listening only on `127.0.0.1` and not `::1`? Or maybe you intend to connect to some remote database but accidentally deleted your DB connection configuration and you are now defaulting to localhost?

Answer (score 0):

mysql> select @@hostname

For some reason this was set to 'r.local', and upon entering that in the connection object it seems to work. Although now it takes a couple of seconds to load, which is a problem.

Comment: What did you do ? I don't understand

Comment: @Leccho after logging into MySQL as root, I entered `SELECT @@hostname` which gave me the correct value to use in the connection object.
Since then I've set it back to 'localhost', and it's working fine. Unfortunately I can't remember exactly what I did but if it's any help, these are the options I use in my connection objects:  
  
charset = 'utf8mb4',  
host = 'localhost',  
database = '...',  
socketPath = '/tmp/mysql.sock',  
port = 3306  
  
running on MacOS